# Application class variables gets uninitialised in android

Tags: java, android, android-memory

I have created an android app in which i'm using an application class to store and access the global variables. But i came across a strange behavior that all the variables in my application class gets uninitialized in the following scenarios,

1. if my app is idle for sometime(say 10 minutes or so).
2. if my app goes to background (if a browser gets opened above the app).

I searched a lot in SO and web and doesn't found any suitable answer. AFAIK once application class is initialized it will be accessible for the lifetime of the application. Am i missing something here?

Since i'm new to android development i may be doing something wrong here. Can anyone point me to the right direction?...Thanks in advance.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

private MyClass classObj = new MyClass();
private boolean flagOne = true;
private boolean flagTwo = false;

void setFlagOne(boolean flag) {
    flagOne = flag;
}

boolean getFlagOne() {
    return flagOne;
}

void setFlagTwo(boolean flag) {
    flagTwo = flag;
}

boolean getFlagTwo() {
    return flagTwo;
}

void setMyClassObj(MyClass obj) {
    classObj = obj;
}

boolean getMyClassObj() {
    return classObj;
}
}
```

Comment: *AFAIK once application class is initialized it will be accessible for the lifetime of the application.*, that's true for static member. BTW what you mean by  *application class* ?

Comment: I mean i'm using a class which extends Application class.

Comment: @blackbelt so how can i fix this?

Comment: How can I know without seeing the code?

Comment: @blackbelt code is added...

Comment: You could override the Application's [onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate()) and log when it is called, to see if the app is being recreated.

Comment: @MisterSmith yes, app is getting recreated

Comment: If `onCreate` is being called more than once, then each time it is called it means the app has been created anew and your vars will be initialized to their default values. You might have to persist them to save their state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last i got it sorted out by saving the variable state using shared preferences and storing the object in application files directory. So if the application recreates at any time (sometimes if the app goes in background) i restore the state of the variables and read the object back. So the variables don't go uninitialised at an point of time.

Storing values,

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("appstate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("flagone", flagOne);
editor.putBoolean("flagtwo", flagTwo);
```

Retrieving values,

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("appstate", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
flagOne = pref.getBoolean("flagone", true);
flagTwo = pref.getBoolean("flagtwo", false);
```

Comment: what u were trying was smart way to get global variable.though this solution my work but this is not smart way.BTW where is onCreate() callback in your application class.I dont know much but check out http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android it may be helpfull

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz Already my application class has the onCreate() call back, Sorry for not mentioning it in the answer. In fact i'm retrieving all the stored values from onCreate() in the application class.