# Accessing android global variables from Broadcast receiver (Alarm) class

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, global-variables

I Would like to make global variables that can be accessed from a broad receiver class (repeating Alarm). To make global variables I used this class:

```
public class GVar extends Application {
private Integer Hour;
private Integer Minute;

public void setHour(Integer hour) {
    Hour = hour;
}

public void setMinute(Integer minute) {
    Minute = minute;
}

public Integer getHour() {
    return Hour;
}

public Integer getMinute() {
    return Minute;
}
}
```

Then my Alarm looks like this:

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static Integer counter=0;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    wl.acquire();

    // Put here YOUR code.
    //start activity
    Integer H=((GVar) this.getApplication()).getHour();

    Intent intentone = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), UssdCallActivity.class);
    intentone.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intentone);
    //startActivity()

    //Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm! ("+counter.toString()+")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // For example
    counter++;
    wl.release();

}
```

getApplication() method can't be resolved.
The same method works when called from MainActivity class.

Comment: firstly did u register application class in manifest  ? If it's ok, you can try context.getHour()

Comment: Application is not designed to save your app's data, you should consider create another class for saving data, eg: a class that can access SharedPreference, or just a Singleton class

Comment: You can check theese questions [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060862/application-class-variables-gets-uninitialised-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24060862/application-class-variables-gets-uninitialised-in-android) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810240/how-to-create-a-global-variable-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810240/how-to-create-a-global-variable-in-android)

Comment: @ersinyildiz yes registered in the manifest:        android:name="com.example.application.AnsarAlsunaDonations.GVar"
context.getHour() doesn't work